# How to execute a simple Rust program compiled with prefer-dynamic?

Tags: macos, rust, dynamic-linking

I've installed Rust compiler via `brew install rust` and I have the following Hello World program:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello World!");
}
```

I've compiled it via: `rustc -Cprefer-dynamic hello.rs` for a smaller size.

However I've got the following error when executing it:

```
$ ./hello 
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libstd-99517fd8418575af.dylib
  Referenced from: mydir/./hello
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Here is the output from `otool`:

```
$ otool -L hello
hello:
    @rpath/libstd-99517fd8418575af.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Basically, if you didn't install runtime library into your system that can't work. Now, how to install this is some thing I don't know.